# CompletableFuture: How to apply a function to multiple CompletableFutures?

Tags: java, concurrency, java-8, java.util.concurrent, completable-future

Suppose I have 3 downloads, framed as completable futures:

```
    CompletableFuture<Doc> dl1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> download("file1"));
    CompletableFuture<Doc> dl2 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> download("file2"));
    CompletableFuture<Doc> dl3 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> download("file3"));
```

Then all of them need to be handled the same way

```
    CompletableFuture<String> s1 = dl1.thenApply(Doc::getFilename);
    CompletableFuture<String> s2 = dl2.thenApply(Doc::getFilename);
    CompletableFuture<String> s3 = dl3.thenApply(Doc::getFilename);
```

And you can imagine multiple functions to be applied, all in parallel.

According to the DRY principle, this example seems inappropriate. So I'm looking for a solution to define only 1 workflow that is executed 3 times, in parallel.

How can this be accomplished?

I tried `allOf`, but that has two problems 1) it starts blocking and 2) the return type can only `run` stuff instead of handle it.

Comment: declare new method which first calls to download, and then to getFilename

Comment: have you thought about putting the files into a list then iterate over them?

Answer (score 6):

```
Stream.of("file1", "file2", "file3") // or your input in any other format, that can easily be transformed to a stream...
      // .parallel() // well... depends...
      .map(s -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> download(s)))
      .map(dl -> dl.thenApply(Doc::getFilename))
      .map(CompletableFuture::join) // if you want to have all the results collected
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Of course also the two `map`-calls can be combined. But at least you do not write everything x times... If you do not like the collection to `List` you can also call something else on it, e.g. `.forEach(System.out::println)`. The `.forEach` has the benefit, that as soon as the response is available, the consumer is called.

Or the classic: just use a loop and a list/array for your input, but you may need to take care of more than you would have with streams